# Force https on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, no-www

I use Apache server to publish my website. The problem is I want to force my website use HTTPS. For example, if someone enters the URL "http://www.alireza.co/contact.html" it should redirect to "https://alireza.co/contact.html".

I created a `.htaccess` file with these rules:

```
# To use 404.html as default 404 error page.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


# To force website use https and remove www. subdomain.
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://alireza.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is now whenever I enter the URL, no matter with `https` or `http`, or with `www.` or without it, I get the error `too many redirects` or `the website is not redirecting properly` in Firefox.

I use [Autistici.org](https://autistici.org) as my host provider. My website is static (HTML/CSS only). I tried a lot of howtos but I had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. The only thing I had to do was rewriting my `.htaccess` file with these simple rules:

```
# To remove www. from URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.alireza\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://alireza.co/$1 [L,R=301]
#To force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# To make 404.html default 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

It's simple `.htaccess` rules to remove `www.` but I made it to redirect to https://alireza.co/$1 instead of http://alireza.co/$1.